# mysql select rows with a different filter when a column is a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a table that tracks all calls made, and I am trying to make a report that shows both calls made and received by a specific `UserID`. Problem is calls can be made as group calls and these calls have different `UserIDs` for those receiving the call. When a call is placed there is an entry made with the `UserID` of the device making the call and has a `CallDirection` of `Initiated`, then an entry will be made for each of the devices the call is being made to, each with the `UserID` of the receiving device and a `CallDirection` of `Received`.

The only thing that ties the entry together is another column labeled `CallID`. They all share the same ID here.

So I want to Query for all call records with a certain `UserID` and if `CallDirection` is `Initiated`, then I want to also get all the rows that have that `CallId` (which will not have the same `UserID` that I am filtering by)

[image: Example of entries]

I just can't seem to rack my brain around how to do this and would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the problem, you can do a self join wherein one copy has the record with `CallDirection` = `Initiated` and other copy is your original table and joining them on `CallID`.

```
SELECT A.RecordID, A.CallID, A.UserID, A.CallDirection 
FROM CALL_HISTORY A 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT RecordID, CallID, UserID, CallDirection FROM CALL_HISTORY WHERE CallDirection="Initiated" AND UserID=10680 ) I 
ON A.CallID = I.CallID
UNION ALL
(SELECT RecordID, CallID, UserID, CallDirection FROM CALL_HISTORY WHERE CallDirection="Received" AND UserID=10680);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vashi
Awesome! That is getting me the the full group of the calls "Initiated" by that user but now I need it to also give me the calls that are "Received".
Here is my query now:

```
SELECT A.RecordID, A.CallID, A.UserID, A.CallDirection
FROM CALL_HISTORY A
INNER JOIN (SELECT RecordID, CallID, UserID, CallDirection 
    FROM CALL_HISTORY 
    WHERE CallDirection="Initiated" 
    AND UserID=10680
) I 
ON A.CallID = I.CallID;
```

Comment: Check the edited answer. Added `UNION ALL` to add `Received` entries as well.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much!